# How to fix drainage clog in the shower?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, clog

Drainage in my bathroom is keep getting clogged. I tried using a snake by drilling manually ... poured at least 4 cans of Drain clog remover on different time period... in the last 3 days.. however, drainage is getting clogged .. it takes so much of time for water to drains through the drainage.

I wonder, is there a better or best chemical which can remove the clogs?

Comment: Have you tried pulling out the snake to see what the clog consists of?

Comment: drainage is U shape , on the other end.. goes straight line.. snake is reachable till the end of U. I am not able to push the snake through the straight line.. i was able to clean the U shaped pipe .. but not further

Comment: I was thinking about any powerful clog remover.. whatever available in the Homedepot or Target is not doing much ... in my case..

Comment: Put a small hook on the end of the snake and see what you retrieve - does partner or daughters have long hair???

Comment: Yes please and also .. same pipe line is connected to kitchen .. most likely cooking oil might also flushed through the same line

Comment: You know that grease and oil should never be put in the drain right?

Comment: Yeah , I agree.. but cooking oil from pan .. not a lot .. but still causing the clog ..

Comment: I used a snake to do the best, but still not yet fixed.. i am facing the slow drain ..

Comment: Does any one have any advice on Sodium Hydroxide .. ? Will that helps.. to clean the clog ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.  Plumbers friend.**
I always start with this.  Use it when the tub is full so you have a column of water to rock back and forth.  Put your back into it, man!  If there is something lodged sideways in there that collects hair, you might be able to dislodge it with effort.

2. **Consider hot water.**

If you suspect it might be a grease clog from the kitchen you could try hot water.  Get a big kettle of hot water and bring it to near boiling then pour it in all at once.  If it is grease that should liquefy it and let it clear.

**3.  Clog remover.**  If I suspect hair clogs I usually start with bleach because I always have some and it is cheap.  Be generous. I buy no splash bleach which in theory should be better because it is gooeyer.  Alkaline stuff like lye or sodium carbonate should work for grease or soap scum.  You should not mix different drain cleaning chemicals. Let water flow between each effort.

Comment: Side note: unlike toilets, tubs and sinks often have a high accessory drain to prevent overflowing if something is on top of the main drain.  You need to plug the high accessory drain to use a plumbers friend or you lose your suction thru that upper channel.  Wet cloth works fine.  Wedge it in there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all liquid drain cleaners is contact time; they need time to dissolve the clot materials, but if there is even a small amount of flow, they drain away and thus stop working. A good snaking job is much much better. If you were using the typical sink snake that is long and thin, try renting the type that is a long flexible spiral steel spring with a way to rotate it. Rotating it is how you get down past the trap. Also as you do it, pull it out every few feet and look at the material on the end to make sure it is getting something. If it is primarily hair, get a good hair trap for the drain to prevent it from going down there in the future.

Comment: per my understanding, we cant just depend on clog remover.. we will have to drill the snake for few feet .. to clean up ..

Comment: @jsotola, you can just click the downvote button again, right?  That works for me.

Comment: Well, I had typed "good snaking bob...", so I fixed that!

Answer (score 0):

Liquid-Plumr Pro-Strength Full Clog Destroyer Plus is a good one. Pour 16oz of the product, let it sit for 15 mins then flush it with hot water. This should get rid of the clog. To prevent future clogs, install shower drain catchers.

Comment: I used to the same brand .. i might have poured 4 bottles of them.. , anyways thanks.. i reached out a plumber for help ..!!

Answer (score 0):

My shower drain gets slow every few months. What works very well is a "drain bladder" ; it threads to the end of a garden hose , put it into the drain and turn the water on full. The bladder inflates to hold firmly in the drain and then water forces the blockage down the sewer.  The "drain bladders" come in several sizes depending on the drain diameter , about $ 20. Every chemical cleaner has been tried and  they do not work.  A commercial plumber cleaned it out once with his power rotor but it cost a lot more than $ 20.